# How to add mailto with froala editor

Tags: froala

At InsertLink button , i add `mailto:myemail@gmail.com`. But it redirect `httpL//...mailto%3Amayemail%40gmail.com.`
I use froala_editor v1.1.5.
How to fix it?
Thanks for your helping!

Comment: Do you reallly mean `maito` spelled incorrectly? Please edit your post and correct any typos.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version it should work without problems. You're using a version that is almost one year old.